# WordPress Child Theme - twentyeleven

Tags: child-theme, css, theme-twenty-eleven

This is my first attempt at creating a child theme based off the WP twentyeleven theme.

To begin with, I am using MAMP on my mac and have the following directory structure:

```
 applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css
                                                  /mytwentyeleven/style.css
```

My URL in my browser appears as: `http://localhost:8888/mysite/`

My problem/query is, when I activate my theme within WP 3.2 and then go and view it, there is no style been applied at all and the header and footer don't appear either.

Based on my directory structure above, I am thinking my style.css within my mytwentyeleven directory is not importing original parent twentyeleven style.css file.

I think my import path is wrong or perhaps something else. Again, this is my first time at creating a child theme.

Here is my child theme style.css file contents:

```
/*
Theme Name: MyTwentyEleven Theme
Author: Me
Description: My TwentyEleven Child Theme CSS
Template: twentyeleven
*/
@import url("../twentyeleven/style.css");
```

Can people please let me know what I have missed as the import url path is not working as from the looks of it, it's not finding the parent twentyeleven style.css file.

Not sure if it's a MAMP thing but I just can't seem to see why it's not working/finding correct path back to parent stylesheet file.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a **WordPress** question. Does your Child Theme work on a live server, but not on your local MAMP stack?

Comment: @Chip Bennett - sorry, do not have access to a live server and not sure why you think that this is not a WordPress query - it's to do with child themes, which is my first attempt. Can you see anything wrong with my style.css file at all? Thanks.

Comment: I can't necessarily tell from the paths you posted.... is your child theme in the themes directory, or in the twentyeleven directory? It should be in themes, alongside twentyeleven

Comment: A CSS `@import` question is a *CSS question*, and not specifically *WordPress-related*. It *might* be a WordPress-related question, if you don't have the parent-child relationship working properly. Can you verify that TwentyEleven is installed, and when activated, displays properly?

Comment: @Rev. Voodoo - it's in my themes directory alongside twentyeleven theme. Can't figure this one out.

Comment: @Chip Bennett - appreciate what you are saying and just thought that it might be the way I have created my child theme style.css. FYI, twentyeleven theme is installed and works perfectly when activated within WP 3.2.1 administration.

Comment: the only difference I can see in my style.css is single vs. double quote @import url('../twentyeleven/style.css');

Comment: And the Child Theme appears in `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Themes`, and you can activate it?

Comment: @Chip Bennett - surely does and can activate it. is there any log I can look at to see if there are any errors as I am not getting an error appearing on the screen?

Comment: What happens if you view style.css through your browser? Is the `@import` call working? (You'll know, if you see twentyeleven's stylesheet imported.) **ALSO** what rendered output do you get in your browser? Are you getting Twenty Eleven's HTML markup, and are just missing the imported stylesheet?

Comment: @Chip Bennett - good idea on viewing through the browser. tried what you suggested and nope, looks like import is NOT woking as I am not seeing twentyeleven stylesheet, which is huge, just see import url('../twentyeleven/style.css'); Further to your query, yes, I am getting HTML markup.

Comment: Re: "*looks like import is NOT [working]*" and "*yes, I am getting HTML markup*" - then the Child Theme is working properly. I suspect that your `@import` call is mal-formed, or else you've got a file-permissions/config setup problem with your MAMP stack.

Comment: Without seeing what else is in your resulting markup, there's no way to debug this problem. Do you have ANY other files in the child theme? To start, you should ONLY have a style.css file. Not an index.php or anything else.

Comment: @Otto - appreciate your help Otto, that did it. I had some other files in my new child theme directory that caused the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your @import doesn't look malformed.  this is what i have on a live site that is running a twenty eleven child theme.

```
/*   
Theme Name: A Twenty Eleven Child Theme
Description: my child theme
Author: helgatheviking
Template: twentyeleven
Version: 1.0

*/

/* Reset browser defaults */
@import url('../twentyeleven/style.css');
```

so assuming that twentyeleven is in the same folder wp-content/themes as your child theme... this should work. did you clear your cache?

Answer (score 0):

Since:

1. Twenty Eleven renders properly
2. Your Child Theme is visible in `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Themes`
3. Your Child Theme can be successfully activated
4. The browser-rendered output of your Child Theme displays the Twenty Eleven markup
5. Your `@import` call is failing in your Child Theme stylesheet

**I suspect that you have a mal-formed `@import` call in your Child Theme's style.css, or else you have a file-permissions/configuration setup problem with your MAMP stack.**

In either case, this doesn't appear to be a *WordPress issue*; WordPress is working properly.

Comment: if it's a permission issue with MAMP, would appreciate some guidance on what to check/how to fix - thanks.